# AEM: 403 Forbidden occurs when call a Post servlet

Tags: java, servlets, csrf, aem

My problem is similar with this: [CQ5: 403 Forbidden occurs when call a Post servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799024/cq5-403-forbidden-occurs-when-call-a-post-servlet?answertab=votes#tab-top) but in AEM 6.1

According to accepted answer of above topic, I must remove POST from Apache Sling Referrer Filter. I wonder if this action is harmful to my system?
And do have better way to fix this issue?

p/s: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 4):

If you are testing your code on author mode, you get `403 forbidden` error for the request. This requires csrf token (Introduced in AEM 6.1 to perform checks on `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests from browser against [CSRF attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)). CSRF token is validated on form submission at the server side. CSRF protection framework is loaded if `granite.jquery` dependency is added or you can declare dependency `granite.csrf.standalone` to use the framework. On publish it should work fine before login.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to POST data to AEM instance from outside AEM, thats the solution. Its not advised for security reasons. But if its a must you could add authentication to your POST requests and setup the CSRF security measures. In addition to this you could setup your dispatcher to allow the POST request only to selective paths and block the remaining. Even so following all this doesn't guarantee complete security.

For alternatives, I am not sure what your use-case is but you could create a form in AEM and handle the POST via that form and on whatever external resource you are trying to currently send POST to AEM, include this form as iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The POST call is needed for the modification of the content. There will be no harm untill unless your instances are not protected by some more request handle mechanism infront of AEM by dispatcher and Akamai servers, where you can do a request filter at dispatcher and before that even at akamai level and allow only the exact post requests for a application specific.

**Dispatch filter example:**

which shows to allow only the post call with a @SlingServlet(paths = "/bin/sling/myproj/exampleauthhandler")

```
/filter {
    /0001  { /glob "*" /type "deny" }
    /0999 { /type "allow" /method "POST" /url "/bin/sling/myproj/exampleauthhandler" }
}
```

More information you can find for AEM dispatcher

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html

we have also methods called PUT and PATCH which is also worthy but not best suited for the real time scenarios.

PATCH :: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789

also an good discussion you can find PUT vs PATCH

[Use of PUT vs PATCH methods in REST API real life scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459418/rest-api-put-vs-patch-with-real-life-examples)