# Getting 403:Forbidden on hitting a post call in AEM-6-AUTHOR

Tags: post, aem

I am currently initiating a POST call which reads the values from a particular path in the content and returns the response. In case of publisher environment, it is working fine, however, in case of author, i am getting 403:Forbidden error. I made sure that the POST option is removed from **apache sling referrer filter** in the **system/console/configMgr**. Kindly suggest the possible reasons for the same and the method to overcome it.

Comment: AEM author 6.x has a built in CSRF which prevents direct POST calls from working on the author instance. 403 can also be returned if the user does not have write permissions on the path.

Comment: On another note: You use a POST request to _get_ data? This is usually what GET requests are used for.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201101/aem-403-forbidden-occurs-when-call-a-post-servlet/39490339#39490339

Answer (score 0):

AEM prevents `POST` calls when you are logged in. You are required to log in when using author mode. Use publish mode **as an anonymous user**.